# Google Apps Script: Email Reminder Have Time Pulled from Column Values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a Google Sheets setup with a script that will create calendar events and set reminder times for those events.

I have everything working with one exception: I want to be able to have a column "Reminder Time" where each cell in that column can have a different reminder time to correspond to a given calendar entry (So for example, for Type A, a calendar event will be created with a reminder 3 days in advance, but for Type B, the calendar event will be created 6 days in advance, so in the "Reminder Time" column, the first cell would be 4320 and the second cell would be 8640 (times in minutes)).

My problem is that Type A and Type B are both being assigned the first value in the "Reminder Time" column (The reminder time column is column 8).

```
function pushToCalendar() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    //Define reminder, THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM SEEMS TO LIE
    var reminder = sheet.getRange(2, 8).getValue();
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 5);
    var values = range.getValues();
    var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('joncodle9gk4@group.calendar.google.com')
    var numValues = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if ((values[i][0].length > 0) && (values[i][3].length > 0)) {
            if (values[i][4] != 'y') {
                var newEventTitle = 'Note Due: ' + values[i][0] + ' - ' + values[i][3];
                var newEvent = calendar.createAllDayEvent(newEventTitle, values[i][2]);
                newEvent.addEmailReminder(reminder);
                var newEventId = newEvent.getId();
                sheet.getRange(i + 2, 5).setValue('y');
                sheet.getRange(i + 2, 6).setValue(newEventId);
            }
        }
        numValues++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "reminder" is only ever read from H2, rather the row for that event. So you need to move your

```
var reminder = sheet.getRange(2,8).getValue();
```

into your row loop:

```
var reminder = sheet.getRange(i+1,8).getValue();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I tried your suggestion, but received the following error: Cannot convert NaN to (class). (line 7, file "")

Comment: If you'd like to share your script with me (andrewr1969 at gmail dot com), or paste all of your code here, I can take a look.